# Java regex, capturing malformed html

Tags: java, regex

I need to parse the date after the hyperlink `latest-all.json.bz2`which is `29-Oct-2019 15:36`
it is from this website:  `https://dumps.wikimedia.org/wikidatawiki/entities/`

if you look at the website source HTML:

```
<a href="latest-all.json.bz2">latest-all.json.bz2</a>                                29-Oct-2019 15:36         42621256074
<a href="latest-all.json.gz">latest-all.json.gz</a>                                 29-Oct-2019 11:51         63776436005
<a href="latest-all.nt.bz2">latest-all.nt.bz2</a>                                  30-Oct-2019 22:46         84032013058
<a href="latest-all.nt.gz">latest-all.nt.gz</a>                                   30-Oct-2019 13:12        108976436346
<a href="latest-all.ttl.bz2">latest-all.ttl.bz2</a>                                 30-Oct-2019 15:43         52462636586
```

you will see that there is no tag associated with it, so I cannot capture it with Jsoup. Instead I have tried to use this reg ex:

```
String html = this.doc.html();
        String patternString = "(latest-all.json.gz<\/a>)(.*)";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patternString);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(html);
        System.out.println(matcher.group(0));
```

but it does not capture the date. Can someone suggest me the regex that will match the desired date?

EDIT: have also tried `(latest[-]all[.]json[.]bz2</a>)[
]*(.*)` but does not work

Comment: from the html you provided, there is no data matched `latest-all.ttl.gz`

Comment: With JSOUP you should be able to traverse to the `<a>` tags and then request the `.text()` which follows. You can process the contents of the `.text()` node with regex to extract the date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your current regex:

```
String patternString = "(latest-all\\.ttl\\.gz<\\/a>)(.*)";
```

This matches a string of the form `latest-all.ttl.gz<\/a>` followed by something, which I don't believe is what you want.

First, in the source HTML you shared, there isn't any occurrence of "latest-all.ttl.gz" (I believe you meant to look for "latest-all.json.bz2" instead). And second, forward slashes do not need escaping in regex.

So, having this in mind, a regex that should do the trick is:

```
String patternString = "(latest-all\\.json\\.bz2</a>)[\\n]*(.*)";
```

(I added the `[\\n]*` part to exclude any new lines between the `<a>` tag and your date).

Comment: I do not believe this does match the string unfortunately,

Comment: which is confusing me, because i would expect this to, it is close to what i tried except one typo

Comment: checked on  https://www.freeformatter.com/java-regex-tester.html#ad-output and also in my script

Comment: You need to call the `matcher.find();` method before trying to fetch the result.

Comment: @qwertyuiop Oh, I made a small mistake. Replace `\n` in my answer by `\\n` (as it's a Java string we need to escape the backslash).

Comment: Plus what @radulfr said. You have two capture groups here, so use `matcher.group(2)` to get whatever got matched by the second capture group.

Comment: I am confum very confused. It works in the terminal in intelliJ but the regex in Java compile time does not

Comment: oh my god, im so sorry, I should have done matcher.find(). Thankyou so much guys!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex like this:

```
\S+ \d{2}:\d{2}
```

[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/BzGV83/1)